# python - How to parse an HTML table

Tags: python, django, parsing, rest

I have a HTML page with about 50 tables on it. Each table has the same layout, but with different values, eg:

```
<table align="right" class="customTableClass">
<tr align="center">
<td width="25" height="25" class="usernum">value1</td>
<td width="25" height="25" class="usernum">value2</td>
<td width="25" height="25" class="usernum">value3</td>
<td width="25" height="25" class="usernum">value4</td>
<td width="25" height="25" class="usernum">value5</td>
<td width="25" height="25" class="usernum">value6</td>
<td width="25" height="25" class="totalnum">otherVal</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My **REST server** is running **django/python** so in my `urls.py` I am calling my `def parse_url():` function which obviously I want to do all the work in. My problem is, I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to python, so literally just don't know where to put my code. I have gotten some code from the `HTMLParser` python docs, and changed it as follows:

```
import urllib, urllib2
from django.http import HttpResponse
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            print "Encountered the beginning of a %s tag" % tag

        def handle_endtag(self, tag):
            print "Encountered the end of a %s tag" % tag

        def handle_data(self, data):
            HttpResponse("Encountered data %s" % data)


    def parse_url(request):
        p = MyHTMLParser()
        url = 'http://www.mysite.com/lists.asp'
        content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        p.feed(content)
        return HttpResponse('DONE')
```

This code, at the moment, doesnt output anything useful. It just prints out `DONE`, which isnt very useful.

How do I use the class methods such as `handle_starttag()`? Shouldnt these be called automatically when I use `p.feed(content)`??

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish in the end is, when I go to `mysite.com/showlist`, to be able to output a list saying:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
value6

othervalue
```

This needs to be done in a loop, because there is roughly 50 tables with different values in each table.

Thanks for helping a beginner!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing the beginning of the answer to stdout, not django.  Here is how to get HTMLParser to do your bidding:

```
import urllib, urllib2
from django.http import HttpResponse
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.capture_data = False
        self.data_list = []
        HTMLParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.capture_data = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'td':
            self.capture_data = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.capture_data and data and not data.isspace():
            self.data_list.append(data)

def parse_url(request):
    p = MyHTMLParser()
    url = 'http://www.mysite.com/lists.asp'
    content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    p.feed(content)
    return HttpResponse(str(p.data_list))
```

I would recommend putting the class into a utils.py file and keeping in the same folder as your views.py.  Then import it in.  This will help keep your views.py manageable by only containing views.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like this is pretty much the solution I was looking for! Its working, but printing out tabs like this: `'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '1', '10', '32', '35', '39', '45', '33', `. Any idea how to filter these out?

Comment: Is it possible to only retrieve data matching `class=usernum` or `class=totalnum`.

Comment: Added `not data.isspace()` to method.  Should filter out the noise.  As eoinzy mentions you can check the attrs var for additional filtering.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)
here is the documentation http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html.

PS: It will be much more flexible including future requirements!